# Copy and paste VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

```
Sub Test()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 1000

Sheets("Test1").Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 10)).Select
Sheets("Test2").Cells(5, 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

Next

End Sub
```

Here is my macro, 
Purpose of this macro, copy Range "Ax:Jx" from Sheet Test 1 to Range "P5:P14" in sheet Test 2

Note : I want to run 1000 scenario to see the impact on some results. So first step, I create looping macro for scenario as you can see above.

I'm stuck at "Sheets("Test1").Range(Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 10)).Select" . How to define this range so that it can loop as x looping.

Comment: I believe there is a lot missing here.  You are copying a variable range into a fixed range.   Selecting a range and copying into another will not require looping.  So I see some contradiction here.  This is problem probably why you are having problems.   Can you define more clearly the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want to run 1000 scenario to see the impact on some results. So first step, I create looping macro for scenario as you can see above. So I need looping there. That's why I got stuck here.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to x looping, and you have x above. Are you having trouble pasting it? or did you change your question?

Comment: So I still see several problems.  One, let's say that you loop 1000 times and select different data on each loop.  Then you paste it into the same destination.  You will overwrite each time and only the last paste will be visible.  Two, you are selecting, but never copying, so when you go to paste, it will be whatever is in you clipboard to start with.  Three, you destination is not the same size as your source.  To get your copy macro code, just record a new macro, select, copy, then paste and you can grab that code.  Let's get you there first.

Comment: @MutjayLee I'm having trouble with selecting Range "Ax:Jx", because I want to select Range "A1:J1" for x =1 and Range "A2:J2" for x = 2 , and so on
This code not working : "Sheets("Test1").Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 10)).Select"

Comment: @Chewy here I'm just trying to make the first step. 

My full code would be After copy and paste range, I have the result, and I copy the result. and proceed to next scenario and copy the result again.

I'm having trouble when selecting the Range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for select or copy/paste:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim x As Integer, sht1, sht2

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Test1")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Test2")

    For x = 1 To 1000

        sht2.Cells(5, 16).Resize(10, 1).Value = _
              Application.Transpose(sht1.Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 10).Value)

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this code. By the way, can u tell me, why my code not working `Sheets("Test1").Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 10)).Select`

Comment: 1. You are only `Select`'ing and not actually copying anything.  2. `Cells(x, 1)` etc will by default refer to the *active sheet*, so if that's not "Test1" then you'll get the infamous 1004 error.

Comment: Oh you're right,thanks for you help. if I use `copy` code there, then it's should be fine right?

Comment: You could use `Copy` but there's no reason to unless you also want to copy over formats.